# Android: I am trying to access the button using id name in main activity but its showing an error

Tags: android, kotlin, button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/createBirthdayButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="@string/press_to_create"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Sample_message_1" />
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        createBirthdayButton      // This is  not working
    }
```

Here id name is "createBirthdayButton" but i am not able to access it in my Main Activity class

Comment: Try `findViewById(R.id.createBirthdayButton)` to get a reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use like this :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 

 lateinit var button : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button = findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you are using view binding
(i can't see that in your code and also you are using         `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`
),
you need to cast your view first like the top comments:

```
Button createBirthdayButton =findViewById(R.id.createBirthdayButton)
```

and if in the future you decided to go with view binding, it will be like this:

```
binding.createBirthdayButton
```